# what does "=>" mean in solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

For example what does this mean? I think it's just syntax for a hashMap but not sure.

```
address chairperson;
mapping(address => Voter) voters;
Proposal[] proposals;
```

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/28227

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what solidity calls [mappings](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#mappings). Depending on your programming background you may refer to them as hashes, dictionaries, associative arrays or similar.

This is the general form:

```
mapping(_KeyType => _ValueType)
```

So in your case you'll have a variable `voters`, which maps addresses to `Voter` instances.